# Could not find function "ggsave"

Tags: r

Could not find function "ggsave" Not sure why this occurs. I looked at several other sources and couldn't find a solution. Last resort

```
library(tidyverse)

apollo_tbl <- read_csv("apollo.csv", col_names = TRUE)


plot1 <- ggplot(data = apollo_tbl, mapping = aes(x = covpercent, y = dayDifference)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Cov Percent",
       y = "Day Difference",
       title = "Add your title here")

ggsave(filename = "apollo_scatter_plot", plot = plot1, device = "png" )
```

Comment: You have to load `ggplot2` first, do this `library(ggplot2)` or if you haven't installed ggplot2 yet install it first using `install.packages("ggplot2")`

Comment: `library(tidyverse)` should load `ggplot2`, which provides `ggsave()`. Is `tidyverse` installed, did the above code give any errors or warnings?